# Rewrite url multiple taxonomy with single custom post type in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two taxonomy named "air-category" and "air-location" and then post type named "air"

Now i need to build a custom url for accessing a post in this like

```
 Example:-       
     air-category = airport    
     air-location = newyork

  http://www.sample.com/airport/newyork
```

How can i generate 2 taxonomy like the above url to access a post , Please Advice.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I have build the url like this for accessing the post associated with the taxonomies like this http://example.com/?air-category=acupressuur&air-location=jersey

Comment: I'm not sure what hook to use here to rewrite the url ,please advice.